# cross-platform, open libraries for C#/Silverlight/.NET audio/video real time streaming

Tags: c#, silverlight, libraries, audio-streaming

I'm looking for a library for conference a/v streaming to a server, which multicasts to all other clients. I've looked at SIP and openh323, and both seem too specialized for voip telephony.

I want the app to be a cross platform Silverlight application (mac and windows), so I don't think I can use DirectSound, right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be mixing apples and oranges in your question.  DirectSound provides an API for accessing sound cards; H.323 and SIP are standards for making a call out.

Silverlight 4 natively provides a couple of simplified APIs that are roughly equivalent to DirectSound, so that you can access the microphone, sound card and webcams.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602282(VS.95).aspx for some details.

But once you've got the sound, you still need to encode it, transmit it, mix it, distribute it, and then receive it. That's where it gets complicated.  Flash has support for all this natively; Silverlight doesn't.  The best open source implementation right now for doing this was put together by SocketCoder and is available on [CodePlex](http://silverlightvideochat.codeplex.com/), but it uses a proprietary signaling/streaming protocol, a proprietary and very inefficient video codec, and a proprietary media server.

From what I can tell, the best option for doing what you want in Silverlight is a closed-source solution provided by [StreamCoders](http://www.streamcoders.com/products/silversuite.html).  It's not open-source, but it supports a reasonable set of open standards, which means that you'd probably be able to use a third-party open-source media server.  You'd want to test to make sure that it's what you need, of course.

Alternatively, you can try your hand at porting any of the various open-source solutions to C#.  I've done this with the Speex pre-processor: it's complicated, but not as difficult as you'd think.  You could presumably do something similar with openH323 and the various C-based codecs that are out there.  You might even try your hand at modifying the Silverlight RTMP implementation by FluorineFx (http://www.fluorinefx.com/) to do what you need to do.  None of this is likely to be simple, of course.